# ASP.NET Core Editable PDF Saving

Tags: asp.net, pdf, razor, controller

I am trying to understand the best way to embed a editable PDF inside of a webpage, allow the user to fill out the form then have it post back to the server to save that file on the server.

I have heard about IText, but have not found any great examples of this being done. I understand I could have the user download the file then upload but thought it would be cool to embed it into the page.

Is there an ideal way, or easier way to do this then what I was thinking? I have tried/thought about calling a controller (but really I think I can reference all of this inside of the from on 'OnPost()'.

Could I just an iframe and request the iframes value from the form?

Comment: I believe your options are; (1) use PDF.js but add the form filling/extraction logic your self. Which is non-trivial, and requires learning the relevant parts of the PDF spec and how PDF.js works. Or (2) you need to find another, usually paid commercial, web based PDF viewer that supports forms. In which case, you should post your question here to get suggestions: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Adobe's new View SDK will allow you to embed the PDF, let users fill in the form data, and then save it to a repository somewhere. After the save, you can use another PDF library tool to find the fields and get the values. adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/viewsdk.html

Comment: I will need to pay for that SDK right from my understanding.